# @PathParam as class variable in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey to build a RESTful Service and I have Servlets which use the same PathParam in multiple methods. So I'd like to store the PathParam value in a global variable instead of local variables in every method.

Something like:

```
@Path("mensas/{mensaID}/dishes/{dishID}")
public class CommentServlet {
//Global PathParams
@PathParam("mensaID")
long mensaID;
@PathParam("dishID")
long dishID;

@GET
@Path("comments")
public String getDishComments() {
    //  ...
}
```

}

Instead of:

```
@Path("mensas/{mensaID}/dishes/{dishID}")
public class CommentServlet {

    @GET
    @Path("comments")
    //Local PathParams
    public String getDishComments(@PathParam("mensaID") long mensaID, @PathParam("dishID") long dishID) {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Or maybe there are some other ways to do this better?

Comment: Just curious: What do you expect to gain from this?

Comment: I would have to set the values just once in one place, and the signature of the methods would be a lot shorter, which I personally prefer. (Assuming the result is the same obviously)

Comment: It can be done. You just need to make sure you register your class as a class (default request scope) and not as a singleton (or as an instance).

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code by extracting all params to a new class (keeping the original `@PathParam` annotation):

```
public class DishParams {
    @PathParam("mensaID")
    private long mensaID;

    @PathParam("dishID")
    private long dishID;

    public long getMensaID() {
        return mensaID;
    }

    public void setMensaID(long mensaID) {
        this.mensaID = mensaID;
    }

    public long getDishID() {
        return dishID;
    }

    public void setDishID(long dishID) {
        this.dishID = dishID;
    }
}
```

and then declare a parameter using the aforementioned class annotated with `@BeanParam`

```
public class CommentServlet {

    @GET
    @Path("comments")
    public String getDishComments(@BeanParam DishParams params) {
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!